# communication complexity lower bound for identifying coordinate in which two strings differ

Tags: communication-complexity

This is a question from Rao and Yehudayoff's "Communication Complexity and Applications" textbook that I've been thinking about for a while. Suppose Alice has a string $x\in\{0,1\}^n$ that is known to have more $0$s then $1$s and Bob has a string $y\in\{0,1\}^n$ that is known to have more $1$s than $0$s. Clearly, $x\neq y$ so there exists some coordinate $i\in[n]$ where $x_i\neq y_i$; Alice and Bob wish to know such an index $i$. We want to show that at least $2\log n$ bits of communication are absolutely necessary.

**What I've tried thus far**: at first, I thought this question was somewhat similar to a different question: if instead of the number of $0$s and $1$s, the guarantees are that $\sum x_i = 0\mod{2}$ and $\sum y_i = 1\mod{2}$, and we wish to compute $i$ where $x_i\neq y_i$, then we can consider the set $S=\{(x,x') : \sum x_i = 0 \text{ and } |x-x'|_{hamming}=1\}$ then we have the following two properties:

- $|S| = n2^{n-1}$ which can be seen combinatorially.
- If a monochromatic rectangle $R$ contains $r$ elements of $S$ then $|R|\geq r^2$. This follows from the fact that if $x'\neq x''$ and $(x,x'), (x,x'')\in S$ then $(x,x'),(x,x'')$ cannot both be in the same $i$-monochromatic rectangle as for any $x$, there is a unique string that only differs from $x$ in the $i^{th}$ coordinate...therefore, if $R = A\times B$ then $|A|,|B|\geq r$ so $|R|\geq r^2$.

The existence of such a set $S$ can be used to construct a lower bound of $2\lceil \log n\rceil$. I tried to find an analogous set for the original problem, but I'm unable to find a set that satisfies both properties. I doubt one exists, because the vast majority of inputs $(x,y)$ differ in several coordinates (ex. for even $n$, $x$ and $y$ are guaranteed to differ in at least $2$ coordinates). Would greatly appreciate any ideas for how to proceed.

Comment: I don't think $2\log_2 n$ bits are necessary, e.g. consider $n=2$.  Then it must be that $x=00$ and $y=11$, and no communication is necessary.  Maybe $2 \log_2(n) - 2$? And does the problem require both Alice and Bob to know the index $i$, or just one of them?

Comment: Yes, both Alice and Bob both need to know some index $i$ on which $x_i\neq y_i$ and they should know the same index. I agree the $n=2$ case is trivial, I'll think about if the $\log_2(n)$ bound works for $n\geq 3$.

Comment: For $n=4$ I'm pretty sure three bits suffice.  But (oddly) I think that for $n=3$ four bits are necessary (or, to be more precise, in the worst case, Alice has to communicate a bit, Bob has to communicate a bit, Alice can pass, then Bob has to communicate a bit).